# Double integral on $D$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to calculate $\lim_{a \rightarrow 0^+} \int_{D_a} {|x| \over {y(1+y^2)}} dx dy$ with $D_a=\{(x,y) \in R^2: {x^2 \over 2} \le y \le 2x^2 ; a \le \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \le {1 \over a} \}$.
If i use polar coordinates the expression of f becames complicated. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

Since the function $$f=\frac{|x|}{y(1+y^2)}$$
is even with respect to $x$, we may just consider the portion $D_a'$ of $D_a$ lying in the 1st quadrant.

Consider the regions $A_a$, $B_a$ lying in the 1st quadrant given as below:
$$A_a: \dfrac{x^2}2\leq y\leq 2x^2; ~~
   -\frac12+\frac12\sqrt{1+a^2}\leq x^2\leq-2+2\sqrt{1+\frac1{a^2}}
$$
$$B_a: \dfrac{x^2}2\leq y\leq 2x^2; ~~
-2+2\sqrt{1+a^2}\leq x^2\leq -2+2\sqrt{1+\frac1{a^2}} 
$$

We see that 
$$A_a< D_a'< B_a$$
and 
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}A_a=\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}D_a'=\lim_{a\rightarrow0+}B_a$$
where 
$$
\lim_{a\rightarrow0}A_a=A:~~ \dfrac{x^2}2\leq y\leq 2x^2; ~~ 0<x
$$
Hence 
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\int_{D_{a}}f=2\int_Af
=x^2\log\frac{8+2x^4}{1+x^4}+4\arctan\frac{x^2}2-\arctan2x^2\Big|^\infty_0
=\infty
$$
(assumming my calculation was correct)

Comment: it was stated in the question.

Comment: sorry, missed that...

Answer (score 0):

$u = x^2\\
v = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$

Then

$x = \sqrt u\\
y = \sqrt {v^2 - u}$

The jacobian is

$\det \begin {bmatrix}\frac {\partial x}{\partial u} &\frac {\partial x}{\partial v}\\\frac {\partial y}{\partial u} &\frac {\partial y}{\partial v}\end{bmatrix}$

$\det \begin {bmatrix}\frac {1}{2\sqrt u} & 0\\\frac {-1}{2\sqrt {v^2 -u}} &\frac {v}{\sqrt {v^2-u}}\end{bmatrix} = \frac{v}{2\sqrt {u}\sqrt {v^2 - u}}$

$2\int_{\frac{1}{a}}^{a}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2} \frac {\sqrt u}{\sqrt {v^2 - u}(1+ v^2 - u)}\frac {v}{2\sqrt {u}\sqrt{v^2-u}} \ du\ dv\\
\int_{\frac{1}{a}}^{a}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2} \frac {v}{(v^2 - u)(1+ v^2 - u)} \ du\ dv\\
\int_{\frac{1}{a}}^{a}\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{2} \frac {v}{(v^2 - u)} - \frac {v}{(1+ v^2 - u)} \ du\ dv$

Comment: why is u  between $1 \over 2 $ and $2$?